# I want to check that an item creation_date has a date and time in it AM in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, compare

I want to check that a column `creation_date` has a date and time in it. I want to make a query that fetches data before 4:00 PM and after 8:00 AM in an oracle sql query.

Creation Date has dates like `12/03/2020 08:02:00 AM`, `12/05/2020 08:02:00 PM`

```
SELECT *
    FROM t1 IH
    WHERE 
          to_char(IH.CREATION_DATE,'HH:MI:SS PM')>to_char('04:00:00 PM')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the time in Oracle, you can convert to a string and compare:

```
select *
from t1
where to_char(creation_date, 'HH24:MI') >= '08:00' and
      to_char(creation_date, 'HH24:MI') < '16:00';
```

Oracle doesn't support a `time` data type, so strings are convenient.

Another method that works because you care about full hours is:

```
where extract(hour from creation_date) between 8 and 15
```

This assumes that `creation_date` is a timetamp.  Or you need to convert it:

```
where extract(hour from cast(creation_date as timestamp)) between 8 and 15
```

Comment: Extract hours is not valid in oracle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2fe30a35d5aaee041b9f058f01b788fe

Comment: @Popeye. . . `extract(hour)` does work, but it assumes the value is a `timestamp`, not a `date`.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculation on `date` and fetch `hours` as follows:

```
select *
 from your_table
where creation_date - trunc(creation date)* 24 between 8 and 16;
```